# Lógica de class em javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Irei receber um **JSON** contendo 2 objetos:
**Player 1** e **Player 2**.

Iria conter a seguinte estrutura:

```
player 1:
playerid
socketid
name
points
jogada
player 2:
player 1:
playerid
socketid
name
points
jogada
```

eu acabei criando isso:

```
const player = require('../models/User');
const jogada = {
    pedra:{
        id:1
    },
    papel:{
        id:2
    },
    tesoura:{
        id:3
    }
}; 
const socketId = null

class Player {
    constructor({socket, name = "", jogada = "", points = ""}) {
        socketId = socket.socket.id
        this.id = player.id;
        this.name = player.name;
        this.points = player.points
        this.jogada = jogada;
    }

}

module.exports = Player;
```

Em java seria mais fácil eu criaria uma List de Players e adicionaria esses dois players nela

Mas eu fiquei na dúvida como faria algo parecido com isso no javascript?

Cria 2 players com os atributos do meu json que irei receber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Se entendi correto, podes fazer assim:

Quando receberes o *json*, creio que estará "arvorizado" em algo parecido com isso:

```
{
   //outros dados
   "players" : [
      "player1" : {
          //dados desse player
      },
      "player2" : {
          //dados desse player
      }
   ]
}
```

Então, pega o *json* e o percorre com um laço de repetição ( um *for* da vida ), tipo assim:

```
for ( let player in json.players ) {
    let { socket, name, jogada, points } = players; // usei desestruturação
    let player = new Player({ socket: socket, name: name, jogada: jogada, points: points }); // instância  
    player.addList(); // add no array ( atributo de classe ) 
}
```

Na sua classe, arruma os atributos para convergir com os parâmetros, adiciona um método para inserir a instância num array ( atributo de classe ) e faça um **atributo de classe**, seria algo assim :

```
Class Player {
    constructor({socket, name = "", jogada = "", points = ""}) {
        this.socketId = socket.socket.id;
        //this.id = player.id; ** aonde vem o player.ID? o construtor não recebe esse parâmetro**
       //this.name = player.name; ** aonde vem o player? o construtor não recebe esse parâmetro**
       //this.points = player.points; ** aonde vem o player? o construtor não recebe esse parâmetro**
       // creio que o correto seria:
       this.name = name;
       this.jogada = jogada;
       this.points = points;
    } 
    addList() {
      Player.list.push( this );
    }
}
Player.list = new Array();
```

[Veja esse link para entender mais sobre atributos de classe e atributos de instâncias](http://planeta-globo.com/2013/04/22/a-diferenca-entre-atributos-de-classe-e-de-instancia/)

Espero ter ajudado 8), e claro, há diversas outras formas de fazer essa lógica, boa sorte com suas linhas de códigos.

Comment: obrigado @Miqueias Moureira